# What is the Big Θ analysis of this function?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
public SomeObject secondFunction(SomeObject obj) {

    SomeObject retVal = new SomeObject

    for data in this.dataCollection {
        for data2 in obj.dataCollection {
            if(someCondition) { 
                retVal.add(data) 
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal
}
```

I’m trying to learn about algorithm analysis. What is the Big Θ analysis 
of the implementation of this function? Why/how?

I don’t think it is an n-squared algorithm, since the two structures being looped through are possibly of different sizes. Intuitively, I want to call it an n*m algorithm, since the number of elements in obj,dataCollection and this.dataCollection are both unknowns. But I’ve never seen that phrasing used before, so it is probably wrong. What is it?

Also, what can we say about best case, worst case, and average case here? It seems like the best and worst cases are the same, since it will loop through all the elements in both structures every time. Is this correct, or wrong? Also, what does this mean about the average case? Would the average case just be the same as the best and worse case in this particular example?

Comment: it is O(N*K) = O(N^2) = Θ(N^2)

Comment: @Lashane -- Thanks for the comment. Why/how is O(nk)=O(n^2)=Θ(N^2), when k could be much bigger, or smaller, than n?

Comment: imagine that N -> infinity and K -> infinity, so lim(N*K) = N^2

Comment: @Lashane: No, Θ(N^2) is definitely *not* the same as Θ(N\*K). There's a precise mathematical definition of what Θ(N\*K) means, and a function that is Θ(N*N) won't satisfy it.

Comment: @psmears it is not the same, but usually we use only N to describe O, Θ, etc, so we can assume N=K=max(N,K) and this is why Θ(N*K)=Θ(N^2)

Comment: @Lashane: For f=O(M\*N) it is valid to substitute max(N,K) to get f=O(max(N,K)^2), because O() gives an upper bound (to within a constant factor), so substituting a bigger upper bound doesn't make the claim false. That's not true for Θ, which gives upper *and* lower bounds (again, to within a constant factor) - so substituting a strictly larger function is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct - it is valid to call it a Θ(n * m) implementation, assuming that the inner loop's body takes constant time (and that the time to perform the actual iteration is insignificant).

As for the best/worse/average cases: again, assuming the inner loop's body takes constant time, then to within a constant factor, they will all be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A couple follow ups: (1) Suppose the add function performs some sorting operation when it adds it to the retVal. Does this preclude it from being constant time within the loop's body, since we don't know how long this will take? (2) If the condition in the inner 'if' statement checked the retVal to see if it contained the value yet (and we don't know how many steps this takes), then does this preclude it from being constant time within the loop body? (3) If yes to either of those, how will this affect the Big Θ analysis?

Comment: (1) It depends what it's sorting! If it's sorting a constant-sized list, the time should be constant; if it's sorting the items added so far, then no, and you'll have to factor the time taken for the sorting into the overall complexity analysis. (2) Again, "it depends". Some tests may be constant time; some may depend on the size of the problem. (3) Again, it depends - but typically you would have to multiply the time taken for these two operations into your overall complexity - so if one was Θ(log N), say, then you might end up with the overall time being Θ(N\*K\*log N)

Comment: Thanks again for the comments. I still have a final question about (2) and (3) though. In one algorithm I'm analyzing, it checks to see if the data has already been added to retVal before adding it. So replace my code's "someCondition" in the if statement with "data.equals(data2) && !retVal.contains(data)," where contains iterates through the linked list of data we've been building, checking for an occurrence. This is not constant time, since we don't know how many items are in retVal on any given pass, correct? If that's the case, then my question is how would I represent this mathematically?

Comment: Assuming the list typically ends up containing N*K items, and that the individual comparisons take constant time, it would likely be Θ(N^2\*K^2).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense if the list ends up containing NxK items. The list will actually have an unknown number of items though. I think it could have up to just N, but it could have as few as 0. This is because it checks whether the value is in both before adding it (and it doesn't add duplicates.) It typically will have something in-between those values. The individual comparisons do take constant time, though.